# Puppeteer on Raspberry PI on ubuntu sometime gives "Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null"

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

This code runs correctly locally every time.  However, when I deploy to the server (ubuntu on Raspberry Pi using chromium-browser) I sometimes get errors around 3/10 attempts.  This code works best...

```
await page.goto('http://mywebsite.com')
const element = await page.$('div[class="user-tags"]')
const value = await page.evaluate(el => el.textContent, element)
```

but sometimes returns... "Error Getting Experience Level Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null"

So I looked around for solutions and tried this but it fails every time (both code blocks run locally fine)...

```
 await page.goto('http://mywebsite.com')
 await page.waitForSelector('div[class="user-tags"]')
 const element = await page.$('div[class="user-tags"]')
 const value = await page.evaluate(el => el.textContent, element)
```

Which throws " Error Getting Experience Level TimeoutError: waiting for selector "div[class="user-tags"]" failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded 9/10/2020 @ 06:02:35"

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The difference between first and second code snippets**

In the second code sample you instruct puppeteer to wait until `div[class="user-tags"]` exists on the target page:

```
await page.waitForSelector('div[class="user-tags"]')
```

That is the correct way of getting data from an element - first make sure it is available, then query it.

Timeout error happens because the given element is not found within 30 seconds (it is the default timeout).

**Ways to solve this**

First you need to figure out why the element is not found by the puppeteer.

- Maybe `div.user-tags` is not supposed to be present on every page?
- Maybe Raspberry Pi is not powerful enough to load and process the target page in 30 seconds? - It is possible to [increase the timeout](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagesetdefaulttimeouttimeout).
- You can also wait until the page is *completely* loaded, this way puppeteer will make sure all of the resources are loaded before going on with the script:

```
await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })
```

Comment: "Maybe Raspberry Pi is not powerful enough" this is what I was thinking!!!  Thanks!!!